# WPF changing button color, with a defined style already in place

Tags: c#, wpf

i've made some rounded buttons, using a  template.  hovering the button changes the colour

MainWindow

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="pressbtn" Command="{Binding TypeChange}" 
  CommandParameter="{Binding Name ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
  Style="{StaticResource btnBlue}" BorderBrush="MidnightBlue" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Press</Button>
```

Style Resource

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnBlue">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0,1,1,0"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

this works fine, but i'd like the button to stay on a background colour until another button is pressed, upon which it would go transparent and the other button would change colour

i have tried (where IsSelected is an integer, with each button triggering the property)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

i've also tried

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>
```

it seems that any of the button events (like `IsPressed`) are transient, so a button press works for a brief period but wont stick.  reading up about the , it appears that it doesn't work because i set the Background inline in the main Setter

`<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>`

However, if i take out that Property, nothing changes

this part of XAML is a weak point (Styles, Templates), and i can't find anything in searching that helps or at least that i understand very well.  Any assistance in getting the `<DataTrigger>` or other method to work is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "sticky" version of `IsPressed`, you should use a `ToggleButton` and bind to its `IsChecked` property.

An ordinary `Button` has no property to indicate whether it has previously been clicked or not.

You will of course also have to write some code that sets the `IsChecked` property back to `false` or `true` when the other `Button` is clicked.

If `IsChecked` doesn't fits your requirements, there is the `Tag` property that you can set to anything.

Comment: thanks, i come from winforms and didn't even know about the togglebutton